# Conditional lookup for nested localfield

Tags: mongodb

I want to get user's friends and their information. But only wanna join for users where "status" equals to 2.

Here is my object

```
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5d2f574b1c27807fd7eb133d"),
    "relationship" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5d2f57661c27807fd7eb133e"),
            "status" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5d2f57c01c27807fd7eb133f"),
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My query

```
db.getCollection('relationships').aggregate([
  {$match: {
      user_id: ObjectId("5d2f574b1c27807fd7eb133d")}
  },
  { $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    as: "users",
    let: { id: "$_id" },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: {
          $expr: { $and: [
              { $eq: [ "$relationship.user_id", "$$id" ] },
              { $eq: [ "$relationship.status", 2 ] }
          ] }
      } }
    ],
  } }
])
```

expected output

```
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5d2f574b1c27807fd7eb133d"),
    "friends" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f57661c27807fd7eb133e"),
            "name" : "Mike"
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the proper way to do this ?

Comment: could you show users schema

Comment: @Ashh 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f57661c27807fd7eb133e"),
    "name" : "Mike"
}

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient for querying if you stored the user's name inside the relationship array? that way you won't have to do any lookups. just an idea :-)